# How to configure which user fcgiwrap runs as on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, configuration, nginx, fastcgi

I have Redmine/Git/nginx/fcgiwrap running in a jail on FreeBSD 9.3 for (potentially) authenticated Git commits over HTTP/S. Everything works until I restart the jail.

In order for a commit to work I need to manually change `/var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.sock` from `srwxr-xr-x root:wheel` to `srwxrwxr-x root:www`.

It seems like there should be a better way to do this so that its persistent over a reboot. My feeling is that there should be some way of telling fcgiwrap who to run as but I can't work out where this is specified on FreeBSD.

The man page says:

> Most  probably  you  will want to launch fcgiwrap by spawn-fcgi using a configuration like this:

```
FCGI_SOCKET=/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock
FCGI_PROGRAM=/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap
FCGI_USER=nginx
FCGI_GROUP=www
FCGI_EXTRA_OPTIONS="-M 0700"
ALLOWED_ENV="PATH"
```

Based on [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/312865/135566) I have looked in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` for `spawn-fcgi` but its not there which I assume means its not installed. It also seems overkill to install spawn-fcgi just to manage who fcgiwrap runs as.

I've found in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/fcgiwrap` it says:

```
# fcgiwrap rc.d script supports multiple profiles (a-la rc.d/nginx)
# When profiles are specified, the non-profile specific parameters become defaults.
# You need to make sure that no two profiles have the same socket parameter.
```

What is a profile and how would I go about creating one for this rc.d script? Or am I going about this all the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Never mind. I was closer to the solution than I thought. Reading through [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/article.html#rcng-args) I just needed to add `fcgiwrap_user="www"` to `/etc/rc.conf`.